# web config file not nested

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my .NET website project, I need to set up the Web.config file for different environments. I read that website projects do not support different environments so the config files will not be nested. I manually set up a `Web.myEnv.config` file and made some additions to the file, but the file is not nested under the Web.config file (only the `Web.debug.config` file is). Is my new `Web.myEnv.config` file going to work even though it is not nested? I am unable to try this myself as I can't access the environment I am setting up the configuration for.

Comment: Which version of `.net` is this for?

Comment: @nurdyguy version 4.8

Comment: @brett, no. Only one .config file will be read in runtime, namely `web` or `app` config. To use a different one, you should try transforming it in build-time. Refer to https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-transformations-the-definitive-syntax-guide/ for more info.

Comment: @EricWu I am not using .net core. The web site project doesn't let me nest an environment specific config file. So I don't know if it will be read even though it is not nested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you handle multiple web.config files for multiple environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592672/how-do-you-handle-multiple-web-config-files-for-multiple-environments)

Comment: @SelimYıldız No, because on a web site project I can't have different Web.config files. I really need a way to change the configuration only in a specific environment in one Web.config file, not have multiple files.