# Custom configuration in .NET

Tags: .net, configuration, configuration-files

I am seeing simple examples regarding custom configuration in .NET. My case is a bit more complex, with nested nodes.

I'd like to be able to read this from the configuration file:

```
 <environments>

<environment name="live" url="http://www.live.com">
  <server name="a" IP="192.168.1.10"></server>
  <server name="b" IP="192.168.1.20"></server>
  <server name="c" IP="192.168.1.30"></server>      
</environment>

<environment name="dev" url="http://www.dev.com">
  <server name="a" IP="192.168.1.10"></server>
  <server name="c" IP="192.168.1.30"></server>
</environment>

<environment name="test" url="http://www.test.com">
  <server name="b" IP="192.168.1.20"></server>
  <server name="d" IP="192.168.1.40"></server>
</environment></environments>
```

If anyone could provide some code for that, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read this by implementing custom configuration classes inheriting from the ConfigurationElement class.

Here is an example of the "server" element:

```
public class ServerElement: ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return ((string)base["name"]); }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

The environment element is actually a collection and could be implemented like this:

```
public class EnvironmentElement: ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement(string elementName)
    {
        return new ServerElement(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks PEter, can you please go on and write the other classes? It's really confusing, how to wire-up the whole thing :/

Comment: Is this enough to get you started? :)

Comment: Sure, thanks very much. I'll try to follow from here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

A nifty tool I came across recently is the [Configuration Section Designer](http://www.codeplex.com/csd) up on CodePlex; integrates into VS nicely.

Generates classes, XML schema, etc. Recommended.

Comment: Excellent tool, has me going with no problems after hours of trying to get things working manually.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your need to create some classes to handle the custom configuration sections of the config file.

There's a very good blog entry by Phil Haack on this: [Custom Configuration Sections in 3 Easy Steps.](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx)

Edit:

I was trying to find the Code Project article I've used in the past to learn how to achieve this, and I've found it on Phil's blog entry:

here it is [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)

it contains the info necessary to handle nested elements and collections.

Answer (score 1):

This example might help : [To create a custom configuration section handler (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Comment: thanks but the example doesn't have a scenario like mine... i've seen lots of simple examples, but not with nested nodes

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the content of your example (targeting different staging environments), rather than reading config files dynamically, you might want to look at [web deployment projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en), as indicated in the [answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment).

They handle config merging at deployment time instead: a good idea, especially if you have sensitive information like connection strings with service account passwords...

Answer (score 0):

I would use App.Config file

System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DatabasePath"];

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10004734/appconfig-file-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I implemented recently after reading this article:

Using Reflection for binding classes to .ini files

http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!174.entry