# Updates to custom configuration section do not write to app.config

Tags: .net, configuration, c#-2.0

After most of the day researching, I am still unable to determine why the following code does not work as expected.

```
    bool complete = false;
    ...
    Configuration cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);                
    BatchCompiler bc = new BatchCompiler(cfg.AppSettings.Settings);

    ... do stuff with bc ...

    // Store the output of the operation.
    BatchCompilerConfiguration bcc = (BatchCompilerConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("BatchCompiler");
    bcc.FilesCopied = complete;
    bcc.OutputPath = bc.OutputPath;
    cfg.Save(); // This does not write the modified properties to App.Config.
    //cfg.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\blah.config") // This creates a new file Blah.Config with the expected section information, as it should.
```

The definition of the BatchCompilerConfiguration:

```
public sealed class BatchCompilerConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    public BatchCompilerConfiguration()
    {
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("filesCopied", DefaultValue = "false")]
    public bool FilesCopied
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBoolean(base["filesCopied"]); }
        set { base["filesCopied"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("outputPath", DefaultValue = "")]
    public string OutputPath
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(base["outputPath"]); }
        set { base["outputPath"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant sections from the App.Config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="BatchCompiler" type="BatchCompiler.BatchCompilerConfiguration, BatchCompiler" />
</configSections>

<BatchCompiler filesCopied="false" outputPath="" />
```

I've looked at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx, the relevant MSDN articles and references for ConfigurationManager, and several existing questions here including:

- [Custom Configuration in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730153/custom-configuration-in-net)
- [Reload configuration settings...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934898/reload-configuration-settings-from-an-external-config-file-during-run-time)
- [Problem implementing Custom Configuration...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080521/problem-implementing-custom-configuration-section-handler)
- and several others.

I wouldn't expect to have to write a full custom element implementation to store the data I'm trying to store. However, if that's the only way to ensure the updated information is written to the App.Config file, I will write one. Please take a look and let me know what I've missed.

Answer (score 1):

If a google search brings you to this question, note this:

ConfigurationManager.GetSection("BatchCompiler") provides an instance of BatchCompiler with properties set to the DefaultValue of the custom attributes of class BatchCompiler.

However, it is **readonly**.  If you think about it, this makes sense.  You've not told ConfigurationManager which file to use, so how could you persist the changes?

`BatchCompilerConfiguration` allows read/write, because of a short cut in implementation.  The orginal poster should not allow values to be set if the inherited `IsReadOnly` method returns true.

To get a read/write section, use

```
BatchCompilerConfiguration sectionconfig =(BatchCompilerConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).Sections["BatchCompiler"];
```