# publishing website in webmatrix with web deploy

Tags: webmatrix, webdeploy

How can I publish my website in Webmatrix that uses a database, using Web Deploy?

My connection string has the configuraions of my local database. Should I change the configurations before publish using the webmatrix publisher?

Is there any best practice to avoid the need to change the connection in web config in all publish times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this article

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/web-development-101-part-9-deploying-your-site

You need to set the connectionstring of your server database instead of your local database on your computer.

Take a look on [Using different Web.config in development and production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment) to set configuration for both enviornment dev and production.

Comment: but how do I tell WebMatrix that I want to use the Web.Release.config when publishing and _not_ the Web.Debug.config? the article you pointed to doesn't mention config files at all

Comment: You can better look at IIS forum (iis.net). The Internet is all about learn new stuff.