# modify an element in web.config

Tags: batch-file, web-config

Every time I switch branches in Git I've got to update one line in one XML file so I can see my images (pulled from an image server) locally. I don't want a permanent solution to change the file (such as gitignore) because that file will change from time to time.

I want to run a batch that will simply alter this one line:

`<add key="Images.RootUrl" value="//images.dev.foo.com:7000/" />`

to

`<add key="Images.RootUrl" value="//imagesperf.foo.com/" />`

I'm trying to implement one of two methods I've found here on SO, but so far they elude me, partly because of all the quotes.

1. creates new file but does not change line:

`cd c:\Projects\Git\foo\Foo.Web.Store
    FINDSTR /I /V /B "Images.RootUrl" Web.config > config.new
    ECHO <add key="Images.RootUrl" value="//imagesperf.foo.com/" /> >> config.new
    REM DEL Web.config
    REM REN Web.new Web.config
    PAUSE`

2. pretty sure I lost the plot about halfway through:

`cd c:\Projects\Git\foo\Foo.Web.Store
    for %%f in (Web.config) do (
      for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%g in ('type "%%f" ^| findstr /n /v "images.dev.foo.com:7000"') do (
        if "%%hx"=="x" (
          echo.>>"tempWeb.config"
        ) else (
          for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%i in ('echo.%%h') do (
            if "%%i"=="images.dev.foo.com:7000" (
              echo.%%i=%%jimagesperf.foo.com>>"tempWeb.config"
            ) else (
              if "%%jx"=="x" (
                echo.%%i>>"tempWeb.config"
              ) else (
                echo.%%i=%%j>>"tempWeb.config"
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
    REM ren Web.config oldWeb.config
    REM ren tempWeb.config Web.config`

Comment: Why not use a simpler and less invasive way of handling something like this.  Since this is iis/asp.net why not use the built in ability to have different configs for different environments?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment

Comment: If a value changes and I pull it without noticing, it will slip through the cracks and not end up in my dev config.

Comment: The transform is partial. You don't need to reproduce the entire file for each environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Batch file do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "replace=<add key="Images.RootUrl" value="//imagesperf.foo.com/" />"

rem Get the number of the target line minus one
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N "Images.RootUrl" Web.config') do set /A lines=%%a-1

rem Redirect the input file to read it via SET /P
< Web.config (

   rem Copy lines before the target one
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do (
      set "line="
      set /P "line="
      echo/!line!
   )

   rem Read the target line and replace it
   set /P "line="
   echo !replace!

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

rem Store the output in a temporary file
) > Web.new

move /Y Web.new Web.config
```

However, if the replaced line does not have to be in the same place than the original, then your first method should work; you just have two small errors:

```
FINDSTR /I /V "Images.RootUrl" Web.config > config.new
ECHO ^<add key="Images.RootUrl" value="//imagesperf.foo.com/" /^> >> config.new
REM DEL Web.config
REM REN Web.new Web.config
PAUSE
```

- The /B switch in FINDSTR look for the string at beginning of the line!
- The `<` and `>` character in ECHO command must be escaped with `^`

Comment: Thank you. With the addition of a 'cd \myDir', that first solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Create a version of the file for the environments you work in and add _ENVNAME at the end of each file.  Set .gitignore to ignore the .xml file.  Then, symlink the .xml file in each environ as appropriate.

For example:

```
some.xml_LOCAL
some.xml_STAGING
some.xml_PRODUCTION
```

On local:

```
ln -s some.xml_LOCAL some.xml
```

In .gitignore

```
/some.xml
```

To be safe, you may also want to remove some.xml from git.

Finally, document this for others.

Comment: Because I'd have to watch for changes to that file and then update each other file.