# Is there a dynamic way of changing/loading the web.config based on environment

Tags: web-config, web.config-transform

Is there a dynamic way of loading the web.config based on environment. like I have local, dev and prod environment, and every time i need make changes when i run in locally or commit any changes to dev/master.

I found something that `<appSettings>` tag in web.config supports a file attribute that will load an external config with it's own set of key/values. These will override any settings you have in your web.config or add to them.

```
<appSettings file=".\EnvironmentSpecificConfigurations\dev.config">

<appSettings file=".\EnvironmentSpecificConfigurations\qa.config">

<appSettings file=".\EnvironmentSpecificConfigurations\production.config">
```

but I am not sure how it works, how do I implement this in my project.
please help.

Comment: I think the subject has already been dealt with here :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Aahhh, I have done this with below approach. here is the link

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-automating-dev-qa-staging-and-production-web-config-settings-with-vs-2005