# Toggle CORS Setting dependent on build

Tags: c#, cors

I would like CORS to be enabled if I build a project using the development settings, and disabled if I use the production settings.

So far I have found you can have different config files based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment)

What I am confused about is how I would apply this for cors

Basically I would want a Web.Debug.Config with cors enabled so something like so

```
<customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 </customHeaders>
```

And then Would I just not add in these Headers in the web.Release.Config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a far easier way of achieving what you want. You could use filters over the classes/methods that you want to enable/disable cors for and then use the #IF DEBUG directives. Example:

```
    #if DEBUG
    [EnableCors("","","")]
    #endif
    public class MyController : ApiController 
    {
    }
```

For this to work you need 2 things.

1. Add cors package from nugget
2. EnableCors in the Register method of your config class. Simply do context.EnableCors();

Comment: I have used the `if DEBUG` before but was not sure if this would apply. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Glad to be of help!