# .NET configure log only for DEBUG

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I've enabled logging on my desktop application by configuring app.config

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="application.log" />
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And then I can log on my application with a line like this

`System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Start tailing file: {0}", watcher.FileLocation);`

Now I want to enable the log file ONLY when I start application on Debug mode, because I don't want to distribute my package with log enabled.

Is there any way to configure it?

Comment: JFYI: take a look at log4net for c# https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial it's really easy and there are a lot of tutorials :)

Comment: I'd recommend [Slow Cheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) and to create a .Debug.Config and .Release.config

Comment: It already works this way.  Project > Properties > Build tab, switch to the Release configuration and untick the "Define TRACE constant" checkbox.

Comment: May I use slow cheetah with VS Community edition? Because I can't see add transform option

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional debug,

```
#if DEBUG
    //Code to execute only in debug mode    
#endif
```

or you can decorate method with Condition like below,

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void RunOnlyWhendebug()
{
}
```

Comment: I thought this but I think the OP wants to change the config file, not scatter these throughout his code.

Comment: Either he can return a bool from conditional function to see debug enabled or can create a common function to invoke from all the logging code. I think one or the other it needs a bit refactoring the code

Comment: Yes, I already know of this pre processor directive, however I don't like it very much to put into code

Comment: [Web config transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment) are a much cleaner solution

Comment: Hmm I do agree config tranformation is cleaner if fine to keep seperate configs

Answer (score -2):

You need a configuration transform. That is, a file which will modify values in 
your configuration files based on what build configuration you specify. For a while they were most commonly seen with web.config files in ASP.NET projects, but with .Net Core and .Net Standard it's easier to set them up for additional configuration files (appsettings.json for example).

I'm not sure what framework you're targeting, but since you specify an app.config file [this walkthrough](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2013/11/using-web-config-transforms-with-app-config-files/) should be helpful.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, a comment at best