# <authorization> tag in web.config causing problems in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

I have an ASP.net Visual Studio project and have the following in the web config:

```
<authorization>
   <allow roles = "Domain\UserGroup" />
   <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

This means that only those users in "Domain\UserGroup" can access the page.

This works fine when the page is published to IIS, however when I am working on the project on my local Visual Studio and run the project using F5, I get

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access is denied.
>
> **Description:** An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

If I take the section out, it runs fine locally.

Is there any way round this other than commenting out the section in web config and reinstating it when it comes to publishing to IIS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using different Web.config in development and production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ADyson for the heads up. Indeed, I needed to be looking at web.config transformations.

In my Web.Release.config I added

```
<authorization xdt:Transform="Insert">
   <allow roles = "Domain\UserGroup" />
   <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

in the system.web section and removed this from my main Web.config.

I also needed to change build configuration to release at it was publishing in Debug mode (and therefore no changes were being made to the web.config file)